# Slicing a Matrix in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have a *numpy.ndarray* (**testData**) with 400 values. I want to reduce these values, choosing one of each two rows and the same for the columns, that is to say, **a reduction of 75%.**

I am try to do that --> `testData[::2,::2]`, but my new testData has 200 values, and I don't obtain the expected result of a data with **100 values**.

This is my code:

```
print(type(testData[0]))  -->  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
print(len(testData[0]))   -->  400

print(len(testData[::2,::2][0])) -->200
```

Comment: This is expected as you're only slicing your first dimension by every second element, which will shrink from 400 to 200. The second `::2` will shrink the second dimension. What is the size before and after (ie. call `testData[0].shape`)?

Comment: Refer the [fancy indexing](https://scipy-lectures.org/intro/numpy/array_object.html#fancy-indexing) , [indexing visuals](https://scipy-lectures.org/intro/numpy/array_object.html#indexing-and-slicing) of using the python numpy array indexing and slicing. This would help you to frame the right format.

Comment: `testData[0].shape` --> (400,), It is a vector, so I have to transform to a 20rows and 20 columns matrix, and then apply the slice.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.